# Why is my standard error for the treatment effect is not giving the right 95% confidence interval in R (meta package)?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-error, meta-analysis

I am trying to do a meta-analysis using risk ratio, lower and upper 95% confidence interval in meta package in R but for example, M study, obtained upper and lower 95%CI ([0.7162; 1.1690]) were different than the original values (0.72-1.18) and I am unsure why this is. Details: using R, "meta" package, metagen function, inputting standard errors of treatment effect and treatment effect.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Used code:

```
meta = metagen(Te,seTE, data=data,sm = "RR", studlab = Name, 
        comb.fixed = FALSE, method.tau = "DL", 
        level.ci= 0.95)
```

Results

[image]

Comment: The original limits are already rounded. How did you calculate the standard error? You could supply the original confidence limits to `metagen` using the `lower` and `upper` arguments. The function then calculates the approximate standard error and the confidence limits should be closer to the original.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I calculated the standard error by manually using the formula: (ln(upper CI)-ln(lower CI))/3.92 Then I added this data into a csv file which I then called upon in the `metagen` function. Thank you, I will try approximating the standard error using those arguments, do you have an example of how to set that up?

Comment: If you cannot sort it out try asking on  the mailing list dedicated to meta-analysis in R https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//